# Accessing Amazon EC2 via Public IP get timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created a new instance and I can't access it from the browser with its public ip and also not with the DNS.

The public ip is: `52.28.188.50`

I receives an error: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

I saw lots of articles about the reasons that may cause it but non of them helped me.

I have a security group attached to the instance:

[image]

What can it be?

Comment: Do you actually have a web server running on those ports on the server? Do you have those ports open in the server's firewall (iptables)?

Comment: @MarkB How can I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to make sure that you have an internet gateway attached to the subnet.

Follow these steps in order to do it:

1. Open the Amazon VPC console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Internet Gateways, and then choose
   Create Internet Gateway.
3. In the Create Internet Gateway dialog box, you can optionally name your Internet gateway, and then choose Yes, Create.
4. Select the Internet gateway that you just created, and then choose Attach to VPC.
5. In the Attach to VPC dialog box, select your VPC from the list, and then choose Yes, Attach.

Route table associated with the subnet should also have appropriate route from your subnet to the internet gateway.

Here is the workflow:

1. Open the Amazon VPC console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Route Tables, and then choose Create Route Table.
3. In the Create Route Table dialog box, optionally name your route table, then select your VPC, and then choose Yes, Create.
4. Select the custom route table that you just created. The details pane displays tabs for working with its routes, associations, and route propagation.
5. On the Routes tab, choose Edit, specify 0.0.0.0/0 in the Destination box, select the Internet gateway ID in the Target list, and then choose Save.
6. On the Subnet Associations tab, choose Edit, select the Associate check box for the subnet, and then choose Save.

Here is the AWS source article:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Instance is running a web server
- Security group is allowing INBOUND port 80 & 443 traffic
- Instance is in a Public Subnet:

  - VPC has an Internet Gateway
  - Subnet has a Route Table directing `0.0.0.0/0` traffic to the Internet
  - Network ACL on the subnet is not blocking any traffic (OK by default)